# Why do I need angle brackets in <$a> when implementing macro based on type?

Tags: rust, macros

I can implement a macro taking a type like this:

```rust
trait Boundable<A> {
    fn max_value() -> A;
}

impl Boundable<u8> for u8 {
    fn max_value() -> u8 { u8::MAX }
}
```

When I turn the `impl` into a macro, why do I need to surround the type itself with angle brackets, as in this?

```rust
macro_rules! impl_boundable {
    ($a:ty) => {
        impl Boundable<$a> for $a {
            fn max_value() -> $a { <$a>::MAX }
        }
    };
}

impl_boundable!(i8);
```

In particular, `<$a>::MAX`. Without it, the compiler gives me error `missing angle brackets in associated item path`. It puzzles me why the macro code needs to be different from the non-macro code.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ec55a7ed51c36120acf77db5d5227094)

Comment: I'm guessing its a guard for reference types or other ambiguities, since `<&T>::func()` and `&T::func()` are different things.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so -- it's matched as `ty`, not `expr`, so even if it were `&T` it couldn't be reparsed as a (partial) expression.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The syntax is `_path_::item`, not `_type_::item`. Valid paths include identifiers and `<T>` for types `T`.

In `u8::MAX`, the `u8` is allowed because it is an identifier, not because it is a type. `[u8; 1]::item` is not allowed.

If your macro takes `$a:ident`, instead of `$a:ty`, it will work as is with types which are also identifiers like `u8`. But, accepting a type `$a:ty`, the generic way to make a path from a type is with angle brackets `<$a>`.

It is also an option for your macro to accept a path directly: `$a:path`. But you are likely to encounter [bug #48067](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48067): the parser cannot figure out how to compose a path from smaller path segments. There is a workaround for this case in the ticket of `use $a as base; base::MAX`.

Comment: Makes sense. I wonder if the special case allowing `u8` to be used as a path is documented anywhere? I tested with `$a:path` but while the macro compiled, I wasn't able to pass bare `u8` to it, so it must be contextual somehow.

Comment: I bet you're encountering 48067. I'll edit.

Comment: Yeah, that must be it. I learned two things today.

Comment: Me too. I didn't find directly relevant documentation, but the issues did help ( https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52307 and issues/PRs linked from there)