# What is "<[_]>" in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

In the [`vec!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html) macro implementation there is this rule:

```
($($x:expr),+ $(,)?) => (
    $crate::__rust_force_expr!(<[_]>::into_vec(box [$($x),+]))
);
```

What exactly is that `<[_]>` in it?

Comment: Whew, Rust is generally pretty readable and intuitive, but `<[_]>::` looks like something straight out of an esolang.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Breaking down the specific parts of the syntax:

- `<T>::f` is the syntax to explicitly call `f` associated with a type `T`. Usually just `T::f` is enough, but pedantically, `::` requires a *path*, which is why it is used here since `[_]` is not. The `<...>` allows any type to be used as a path. See [Why do I need angle brackets in <$a> when implementing macro based on type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286508/why-do-i-need-angle-brackets-in-a-when-implementing-macro-based-on-type)
- `[T]` is the type denoting a [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) of type `T`.
- `_` used as a type is a placeholder or "wildcard". It is not a type itself, but serves to indicate that the type should be inferred. See [What does it mean to instantiate a Rust generic with an underscore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215739/what-does-it-mean-to-instantiate-a-rust-generic-with-an-underscore)

Comment: For reference: [Qualified paths](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#qualified-paths).

Comment: This answer is a perfect explanation for `<[()]>` in the Rust Macro book. https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/blk-counting.html#slice-length

Answer (score 15):

Let's go step by step to see how `<[_]>::into_vec(box [$($x),+])` produces a `Vec`:

1. `[$($x),+]` expands to an array of input elements: `[1, 2, 3]`
2. `box ...` puts that into a `Box`. `box` expressions are nightly-only syntax sugar for `Box::new`: `box 5` is syntax sugar for `Box::new(5)` (actually it's the other way around: internally `Box::new` uses `box`, which is implemented in the compiler)
3. `<[_]>::into_vec(...)` calls the `to_vec` method on a slice containing elements that have an inferred type (`[_]`). Wrapping the `[_]` in angled brackets is needed for syntactic reasons to call an method on a slice type. And `into_vec` is a function that takes a boxed slice and produces a `Vec`:

   ```
   pub fn into_vec<A: Allocator>(self: Box<Self, A>) -> Vec<T, A> {
       // ...
   }
   ```

This *could* be done in many simpler ways, but this code was fine-tuned to improve the performance of `vec!`. For instance, since the size of the `Vec` can be known in an advance, `into_vec` doesn't cause the `Vec` to be reallocated during its construction.