# How do I fix this "no rules expected" when calling a rust macro in a macro?

Tags: rust, macros

Trying to learn Rust macros.  I decided to make a macro which operates like the `vec!` macro, but wraps the arguments in `NonZeroUsize`.  My attempt was:

```
macro_rules! nzvec {
    ($T:ty, $($x:expr),* ) => {
        vec![$($T::new($x).unwrap()),*];
    }
}
```

I want calling `nzvec![NonZeroU32, 1, 2]` to produce `vec![NonZeroU32::new(1).unwrap(), NonZeroU32::new(2).unwrap()]` and then to further expand using the `vec` macro.  Instead I got an error:

```
error: no rules expected the token `NonZeroU32`
  --> src/main.rs:5:12
   |
5  |     vec![$($T::new($x).unwrap()),*];
   |            ^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
...
10 |   let vec: Vec<NonZeroU32> = nzvec![NonZeroU32, 1, 2, 3];
   |                              --------------------------- in this macro invocation
```

I then ran `cargo rustc -- -Z trace-macros` and got:

```
note: trace_macro
  --> src/main.rs:10:30
   |
10 |   let vec: Vec<NonZeroU32> = nzvec![NonZeroU32, 1, 2, 3];
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: expanding `nzvec! { NonZeroU32, 1, 2, 3 }`
   = note: to `vec!
           [NonZeroU32 :: new(1).unwrap(), NonZeroU32 :: new(2).unwrap(), NonZeroU32 ::
            new(3).unwrap()] ;`
   = note: expanding `vec! { NonZeroU32 :: new(1).unwrap(), NonZeroU32 :: new(2).unwrap(), NonZeroU32 ::
           new(3).unwrap() }`
```

which looks to me like the macro is working correctly... what gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler error could probably be better, but it is because `$T::new` isn't really valid. It needs to be `<$T>::new`, then it compiles ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=91bcc2a497304af64f0d84f0fb0fde5c)):

```
macro_rules! nzvec {
    ($T:ty, $($x:expr),* ) => {
        vec![$(<$T>::new($x).unwrap()),*]
    }
}
```

See [Why do I need angle brackets in <$a> when implementing macro based on type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286508/why-do-i-need-angle-brackets-in-a-when-implementing-macro-based-on-type)